# callback on code igniter always return false

Tags: php

i am currently making this part that can create something to input to database. i used callback function of code igniter to check availability of some item code of a non auto increment table.

i always get the message of the callback '{field} exists.' how do i fix this?

controllers

// CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public function create(){


    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('JOB_CODE','Job Code','trim|required|min_length[2]|max_length[5]|callback_check_if_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('JOB_NAME','Job Name','trim|required|max_length[30]');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        $this->add_view();
    }else{

        $input = array(
            'JOB_CODE' => $this->input->post('JOB_CODE'),
            'JOB_NAME' => $this->input->post('JOB_NAME')
            );
        $this->Job_Titles_Model->insert($input);

    }

}
```

/////////// FOR TABLES WITH NO AUTO INREMENT

```
public function check_if_exists($jobcode){

    $this->load->model('Job_Titles_Model');
    $availability = $this->Job_Titles_Model->check_if_exists($jobcode);

    if($availability){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

models

/////  CREATE /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
public function insert($input){


    $insert = $this->db->insert('job_titles',$input);
}
```

/////////// FOR TABLES WITH NO AUTO INREMENT

```
public function check_if_exists($jobcode){ //CHECK IF JOBODE IS AVAILABLE

    $sql = ('SELECT * FROM job_titles WHERE JOB_CODE = ?');
    $data = array('JOB_CODE' => $this->input->post('JOB_CODE'));

    if($result->num_rows() == 0){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: ps. i added this to form_validation_lang.php `$lang['check_if_exists'] = '{field} exists.';`